# how to upload and store 3d images in laravel

Tags: laravel, file, object, file-upload, 3d

I am using input file type

```
<input type="file" name="file-3D" id="file-3D>
```

And here is the code in my controller, where I have a variable $product with model Product and I have column name called threeD_img

```
        if ($request->hasFile('file-3D')) {


          $threeD_image = $request->file('file-3D');
  
          $hashedname   = $threeD_image->hashName();


          $threeD_image->storeAs('public/product/', $hashedname   );

          $product->threeD_img =$hashedname;
        
    }
```

However, when I upload the file and store the 3d images with extension .gltf, I either get null value or .json file with some objects.

How  would I upload and store 3d objects into my file system ?

I already tested the code with jpg, png images and it works fine.

Comment: Have you had any luck solving this issue?

Comment: @DarwinMarcelo Never ..

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that you just need to change the way you upload file:

```php
Storage::disk('public')->put('assets/' . $request->file3d->getClientOriginalName(), $request->file3d->get());
```

The code above will let you upload/save any kind of file to your server, and will avoid converting it to any weird kind of file such as `.bin`, `.json` or null.